# Shared printer over remote network

Tags: windows, networking, network-printer

I have configured shared printer. When i am in the same subnet as print server (192.168.0.128/25) i can print but when i am in another subnet (192.168.0.0/25) (ping to print server 192.168.0.202 works) every print i get error `Error - Printing` (I have Czech Windows, that is word to word translated)

[image: Print queue]

If i reconect to right subnet printing starts. Is there any way to allow Windows printing on printer in remote network?

Comment: How come your print server has the IP 192.168.1.100, and the print dialog displays 192.168.0.202?

Comment: In real there are more complicated subnets. in dialog you imagine 192.168.1.100 instead 192.168.0.202.

Comment: Did it occur to you that your issues may be caused precisely by these more complicated subnets you didn't describe? The setup in your question should work, so unless you provide more info I don't see what kind of answer you could expect to get.

Comment: Question is updated with real addreses.

Comment: You can do this, but only if network allows it.  If there is a firewall and/or gateway issue you will not cross subnets.  Generally, if you can access the internet your gateway is right on the PC.  However, is the gateway on the printer correct?

Comment: I have tried it with firewall turned off on computer and had no effect. Network between computer and print server are made by 2 OpenWRT routers and Print server is Raspberry PI with installed samba. Everything can ping everything, Internet too.